# Variable path in *.reg file

Tags: windows-registry

I've been a lurker here for a long time and nearly always found a question to my answer using the search question, but this time I need some help. I want to create a script/.reg file that automatically registers some Powerpoint AddIns to the computers in my domain. Pretty straightforward, it needs to do this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\PPMacro]
"AutoLoad"=dword:ffffffff 
"Path"="C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\AddIns\\PPMacro.ppam"
```

Basically, it makes an entry in Powerpoint's registry pointing it to a macro in the AppData folder. However, while this 'Path' key is a static path to the macro, I would like this static path to have a variable username in the script, since this differs per computer I want to apply the script to.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. It keeps literally putting %USERNAME% in the key, which is logical since it's in parenthesis, but I don't know how I am supposed to do it. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the REG command:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\PPMacro" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\AddIns\\PPMacro.ppam" /f
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I actually changed %USERNAME% to %USERPROFILE%, since some of our users have a <username>.<domain> user folder. However your comment pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: So I take it this means its not possible to do in a reg file?  I have also observed %AppData% isnt working e.g.  It is added to the registry properly but path not been intepreted.

Answer (score 1):

To write in the registry you can use powershell and these commmandlets :

```
$RegKey="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\PPMacro"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name AutoLoad -Value ffffffff 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name Path -Value "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\AddIns\\PPMacro.ppam"
```

or, for creating a new entry you can use `new-item`

And for the username, you can use the global variable %USERNAME%. With a GPO, you will be able to execute this script on all desired computer.

.

Comment: I actually prefer to do it through a bat script, so Greg's solution is more suitable. Many thanks for taking the time to answer my question though!